# how to open dialog fragment class from activity that is dialog themed android

Tags: android

I am trying to open a class that extends DialogFragment from an Activity that is set to ThemeDialog, but launching it nothing happens when finish() method is used. If not used the Activity appears behind the dialog window

ChooseTypeActivity  // ThemeDialog activity

```
MyDialogFragment mdf=MyDialogFragment.newInstance(getBaseContext(),R.drawable.account_type, "Set Title name :",null,CHOOSE_TYPE_ACTIVITY);
            mdf.setCancelable(false);
            mdf.show(getFragmentManager(),"dialog");
            this.finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Activity` will contain the `Fragment` you're creating, so when you `finish()` the `Activity` you're also in turn disposing of the `Fragment`. Fragments need host Activities. Sounds like all is working as expected: your `DialogFragment` is appearing as a dialog on top of the Activity - what is the behavior you're intending?

Comment: what would you like it to do?

Comment: I want to exit the activity when dialog is shown --- what is alternative way to do that ???